# Error by this code

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I fill out the form and click registration, it shows an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error is here:

```
int temp=Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Which object must be added to refrence?

Here is the code of the web page:

```
public partial class register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.DataBind();
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new 
                SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionS
                tring"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string checkuser = "SELECT * FROM [Table] where user_name ='" + 
                Text_username + "'";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand (checkuser , conn);
            int temp=Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (temp == 1){
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text_fname.Text = "";
        Text_lname.Text = "";
        Text_email.Text = "";
        Text_password.Text = "";
        Text_password_again.Text = "";
        Text_username.Text = "";
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            SqlConnection conn = new 
                SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionS
                tring"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insert = "insert into Table 
                (user_fname,user_lname,user_email,user_password,user_name) values (@firstName 
                ,@lastName ,@Email ,@passWord ,@userName)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand (insert , conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", Text_fname.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", Text_lname.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Text_email.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@passWord", Text_password.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Text_username.Text);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("Registration is successful");
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From the error message you have posted, it is clear that the `com.ExecuteScalar()` is null. Hence, when you call the `ToString` method on it you get a null reference exception. Since the `com.ExecuteScalar()` can be null, I suggest you do a check for this.

```
int temp;
var result = com.ExecuteScalar();
if(result != null)
{
    temp = Convert.ToInt32(result.ToString());
}

if (temp == 1)
{
    Response.Write("User already exists");
}
```